# Red Hat 7 XFS partition could not be mounted (can't read superblock)

Tags: redhat, xfs

I have a problem with several mounts. Can't read superbock is the error as reported below as example. I tried xfs_repair with/without -L but still got issue. Could someone advice?

```
# mount /dev/lvm02/backup.vol /backup/
mount: /dev/mapper/lvm02-backup.vol: can't read superblock

# xfs_repair /dev/lvm02/backup.vol
Phase 1 - find and verify superblock...
Phase 2 - using internal log
        - zero log...
ERROR: The filesystem has valuable metadata changes in a log which needs to
be replayed.  Mount the filesystem to replay the log, and unmount it before
re-running xfs_repair.  If you are unable to mount the filesystem, then use
the -L option to destroy the log and attempt a repair.
Note that destroying the log may cause corruption -- please attempt a mount
of the filesystem before doing this.

# xfs_repair -L /dev/lvm02/backup.vol
Phase 1 - find and verify superblock...
Phase 2 - using internal log
        - zero log...
ALERT: The filesystem has valuable metadata changes in a log which is being
destroyed because the -L option was used.
xfs_repair: libxfs_device_zero write failed: Input/output error
```

I also tried to remove the lv

```
# lvremove /dev/lvm02/backup.vol
Do you really want to remove active logical volume lvm02/backup.vol? [y/n]: y
  Error writing device /dev/vdb1 at 29696 length 3403.
  bcache_invalidate: block (4, 0) still dirty
  Failed to write metadata to /dev/vdb1 fd -1
  WARNING: Failed to write an MDA of VG lvm02.
  Error writing device /dev/vdb2 at 28672 length 3403.
  bcache_invalidate: block (4, 0) still dirty
  Failed to write metadata to /dev/vdb2 fd -1
  WARNING: Failed to write an MDA of VG lvm02.
  Error writing device /dev/vdb3 at 28672 length 3403.
  bcache_invalidate: block (4, 0) still dirty
  Failed to write metadata to /dev/vdb3 fd -1
  WARNING: Failed to write an MDA of VG lvm02.
  Failed to write VG lvm02.


# lvcreate --name backup2.vol --size 10G lvm02
  Error writing device /dev/vdb1 at 29696 length 4059.
  bcache_invalidate: block (5, 0) still dirty
  Failed to write metadata to /dev/vdb1 fd -1
  Failed to write VG lvm02.
```

Comment: So is it just your backup volumes you've lost? Is so then just create new ones and start backing up again, that said it sounds like there's something underlying that's amiss.

Comment: What is the physical device used? SATA/SAS/SSD or a SAN? 
Also can you share the output of dmesg?

Comment: No, it's not only backup volume, I have several volumes in the same state. This is a VM under OpenStack with external storage (storage not handled by me). DMESG:
[ 4433.566717] XFS (dm-7): log mount failed
[ 4476.398736] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev vdb, sector 35653727
[ 4588.092455] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev vdb, sector 35653727
[ 4759.585102] XFS (dm-7): Mounting V5 Filesystem
[ 4759.616001] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev vdb, sector 35673742
[ 4759.616997] XFS (dm-7): xfs_do_force_shutdown(0x1) called from line 1251 of file fs/xfs/xfs_buf.c.

Comment: This is a single VM with both the original AND backup volumes attached?

Comment: This is a single VM, but do not focus to backup volume, I have 8 LVs on LVM02, and with all of them I got can't read superblock while I tried to mount them. The strange thing is if I try to create a LV on LVM02 group it fails. It fails even if I try to delete and existing LV. As shown in main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved, It was very stupid one.
No more space on cinder mount! Unfortunately I don't have access to the storage so I couldn't check before.

Comment: Since this is resolved and you have described your issue here you can accept this as answer I guess.